# Showing only certain product attributed in a view rather than them all in Commerce

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal Product Pricing, Product Options and Product attributed modules.

I have created a number of different attributes for products but my issue is that when including them in a view it just displays all of them.

This is an issue since I am using Billy Mail PDF module which uses a line item view. So when I include the attributes in the view it just displays them all. This includes an image and potentially alot of text which could be inputted by the customer.

I just need to include 1 of the product attributes but this does not seem to be possible as there is no option for this inside the fields settings in views.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in the form of a patch here > https://www.drupal.org/node/1696656